# GRPC - why are there no minor releases of grpc on maven central?

Tags: grpc, release-management

I noticed that the latest stable version of grpc is 1.8.3

But maven central only seems to have https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-core 1.8.0

Why is that? Why are there no minor releases on the maven central?

Comment: I don't know where you saw that, the latest stable version is 1.9.0. Maybe the version was changed. There are minor versions in there in any case, 1.7.1 was published for example.

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases says 1.9 is a pre-release thus why i said latest stable. i might have this understanding wrong

Comment: grpc community is urged to ask questions here with the grpc tag instead of asking them as "issue"'s in the github issues tracker for github. but the problem is some jerk will "-1" you if they don't like your question. So i'm not going to use this for that anymore. i'll stick to the mailing list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only grpc/grpc (the C-based repo) had a 1.8.3 release.

If you look at [grpc/grpc-java's releases](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/releases) you'll see 1.8.0 is the latest 1.8.x release and there is a 1.9.0 release as well, which aligns with what you see on Maven Central. C is close to releasing 1.9.0, as there is a 1.9.0-pre3 release candidate.

There is some coordination between Java, Go, and C's releases for major and minor releases, but none for patch (bug-fix) releases.

Comment: OK so that explains it. For the java dependencies, there is only a 1.8.0, 1.9.0 etc.